# How to alter MQT query

Tags: db2

I have not been able to find an example of altering the underlying query defined for a MQT.
Are you supposed to drop the table and recreate it?

If you can would this be the correct way?

```
ALTER TABLE SCHEMA.MY_TABLE
(SELECT...)
DATA INITIALLY DEFERRED
REFRESH DEFERRED
MAINTAINED BY SYSTEM
```

Comment: Why not just recreate it?

Comment: Have you tried to look at the "[ALTER TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-alter-table) ADD / DROP QUERY" statement description?